# Version number in jar name - how to handle persistence.xml?

Tags: java, maven, jar, persistence

We are building ear-files with a large number of jars. Some of them contain persistence.xml files defining persistence units which reference other jars with

```
<jar-file>other.jar</jar-file>
```

Now we plan to use Maven in the future and jar names now contain version numbers. This is a huge problem for the mechanism described above: Instead of `other.jar`, we need to specify `other-1.2.3.jar`. But the correct version number cannot be known when the jar is built because in the construction of the ear, the dependency mediation could replace `other-1.2.3.jar` with `other-2.3.4.jar` so that my reference in the persistence.xml of the jar becomes invalid.

So my question is: How can I manage the persistence.xml files properly in Maven when building a large ear file?

---

EDIT:

Let me try to construct a small examples to make my point clearer:

Let us have `first-ejb-1.0.0.jar` depending on `other-1.2.3.jar` and `second-ejb-1.0.0.jar` depending on `other-2.3.4.jar`. Both `first-ejb-1.0.0.jar` and `second-ejb-1.0.0.jar` contain a persistence.xml with a `<jar-file>` entry. `first-ejb-1.0.0.jar` points to `other-1.2.3.jar` and `second-ejb-1.0.0.jar` points to `other-2.3.4.jar`. So far, so good.

Now I build an ear from `first-ejb-1.0.0.jar` and `second-ejb-1.0.0.jar`. The dependencies are resolved, but only one of the `other-*.jar` can be included in the ear. Say, our dependency mediation chooses `other-2.3.4.jar`. Then `first-ejb-1.0.0.jar` has a dead `<jar-file>` entry, pointing to a non-existent jar.

Comment: 1-hint is "Maven resource filtering" is the standard way doing such things. 2-hint using spring "entityManagerFactory" has property "packagesToScan" allows you to find entities in list of packages, so refering by package name instead of jar name.

Comment: @Hishamkh: Could you be more specific about the first hint?

Comment: i think other.jar is one of your project. why should the dependency mediation decide which version to select?? is other.jar not a direct dependency to your project??

Comment: please update with pom structure how you plan to put things together, so you may get concrete answer.

Comment: The problem is as follows: When I build the jar, I can specify the version of other.jar, but when somebody else builds the ear, there might be a different version in it: Maybe, somebody else built his jar with 2.3.4, and the ear now contains 2.3.4 of other.jar. The problem is that the persistence.xml is created when the jar is compiled but it is read when the ear is built.

Comment: so you mean other.jar may be RELEASED independent of the ear RELEASE?

Comment: Yes. The release versions of the jars are produced independently by the different groups. Some jars might stay the same for 2 years, other often change. The ear reflects the latest releases. The old jars might reference an old version of other.jar, the newer jars reference a new version of other.jar. The ear usually picks the newest version of other.jar.

Answer (score 4):

The `maven-ear-plugin` has a property `fileNameMapping` by which you can specify the file name mapping to use for all dependencies included in the EAR file. The following values are valid `standard`, `no-version`, `full`, `no-version-for-ejb`. The `standard` means the filename is the artifactId incl. the version of the artifact. The `no-version` means the files is only the artifactId without the version. The `full` means the filename is the groupId+artifactId+version of the artifact. The `no-version-for-ejb` means the filename is the artifactId without the version in case of EJB type.

So specifying the ear plugin as follows:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
    <configuration>
       <fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

might do the trick for you.

**Alternative 2: Externalize persistence.xml**

An alternative approach could be to externalize the `persistence.xml`. The most straight forward approach would be to create a jar containing the `persistence.xml` and put it into the lib folder of the ear:

```
EAR +
    |- lib +
    |      |- core-module.jar
    |      \- persistence-module.jar +
    |                                 \- META-INF +
    |                                              \- persistence.xml
    |- ejb1-module.jar
    \- ejb2-module.jar
```

EJB modules may be either jar archives or exploded directories. In the setup as above the `persistence.xml` would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="my-persistence-unit">
        <!-- Note: it's relative to `persistence-module.jar` file location in EAR -->
        <jar-file>../ejb1-module.jar</jar-file>
        <jar-file>../ejb2-module.jar</jar-file>
        ....
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

A persistence unit that is defined at the level of the EAR is generally visible to all components in the application. However, if a persistence unit of the same name is defined by an EJB-JAR, WAR, or application jar file within the EAR, the persistence unit of that name defined at EAR level will not be visible to the components defined by that EJB-JAR, WAR, or application jar file unless the persistence unit reference uses the persistence unit name `#` syntax to specify a path name to disambiguate the reference. When the `#` syntax is used, the path name is relative to the referencing application component jar file. For example, the syntax `../lib/persistenceUnitRoot.jar#myPersistenceUnit` refers to a persistence unit whose name, as specified in the name element of the `persistence.xml` file, is `myPersistenceUnit` and for which the relative path name of the root of the persistence unit is `../lib/persistenceUnitRoot.jar`.

The persistence unit can be specified by annotating the entityManager with `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "../lib/persistenceUnitRoot.jar#myPersistenceUnit")`.

Comment: Thank you. As I said in the comment to the answer of @Anton Koscejev, this is a useful workaround, but I would prefer a Maven-like solution with version numbers in the file names.

Comment: Can't you use maven filtering and have instead of `<jar-file>other.jar</jar-file>` something like `<jar-file>other-${other.version}.jar</jar-file>`.

Comment: As I said in the question: The ear build might replace jars by other versions of the same jar. So the reference I give during the build of the jar might not be working any more.

Comment: And there is no possibility to have the persistence.xml external (or override in the ear?)

Comment: Maybe. It would be great if someone who did something like this before tells me about it.

Comment: Updated answer with alternative approach in externalizing persistence.xml

Comment: The Maven WAR plugin also supports configuraton such as <outputFileNameMapping>@{artifactId}@.@{extension}@</outputFileNameMapping>

Answer (score 3):

Since you have a **EAR** project and  an **Other** project, I assume you have a parent project.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by

> But the correct version number cannot be known when the jar is built because in the construction of the ear, the dependency mediation could replace other-1.2.3.jar with other-2.3.4.jar

I understand that **other** does not know its version until **ear** is built (but why?).
You can do the following: in the parent project, define a variable to hold the actual final version.

```
<properties>
  <my.final.version>...</my.final.version>
</properties>
```

Obviously, **my.final.version** should be set with your actual expected value.
Then, Change persistence.xml to this:

```
<jar-file>other-${my.final.version}.jar</jar-file>
```

Then, in **other**'s pom.xml, add this:

```
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</build>
```

Enabling filtering tells maven to replace variables.

You may wish to fine tune the filtering if you don't want to do filtering on all resources (for performance or what ever other reason). Look for the tag **includes** under .

Comment: Sorry, if you got me wrong: When the ear is built, the dependency tree of the ejbs in it is resolved. Different jars in my ear can depend on different versions of other.jar. Only one of these versions is put into the ear (following dependency mediation). But during the build of the jars, we cannot know which version "wins" in the dependency mediation of the ear. The jars are often built much earlier than the ear.

Comment: My bad! So my answer isn't relevant at all. You may take a look at ${maven.dependency.GROUP_ID.ARTIFACT_ID.jar.path}, it returns the full path to the actual jar dependency. Even with this, you'll need to find a way to strip the path in order to keep only the filename...

Answer (score 2):

So, like you said yourself, by the time you are building EAR, your artifact is built, the `jar-file` is already defined and cannot be changed. There are, therefore, two options:

1. `jar-file` must be a specific version - do not allow other versions to be used
2. `jar-file` can be any version - exclude version from jar name

**1. Strict version**

You can force Maven to consider only a specific version of dependency by using [single-version range](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>my.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>persistence</artifactId>
  <!-- require specifically this version -->
  <version>[1.0.2]</version>
</dependency>
```

**2. Exclude version from jar name**

You can add jars to EAR with any name, [even without version](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/customizing-a-module-filename.html):

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
        <configuration>
           <modules>
             <ejbModule>
               <groupId>my.company</groupId>
               <artifactId>persistence</artifactId>
               <!-- rename artifact in ear -->
               <bundleFileName>persistence.jar</bundleFileName>
             </ejbModule>
          </modules>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: You can also remove versions from all artifacts in EAR: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/customize-file-name-mapping.html

Comment: You can also combine version ranges with Maven properties: `<version>[${persistence.version}]</version>`.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm afraid this is not really satisfactory. The first solution goes against the way ears are built in our company (a central group collects the versions - I cannot fix the version in advance). The second solution will definitely work, but violates the Maven way of putting version numbers in file names. Nevertheless, if I get no better approach, I will use the second version (as in your comment) as a workaround until something better comes up.